Example that $\mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{Top}_\ast}$ is not $n$-excisive
I am learning about Goodwillie calculus and wanted to come up with an example that the identity functor on (pointed) topological spaces is not $n$-excisive for any n. Hence I want an $n$-cube $\chi\colon \mathcal{P}(\lbrace 0,\dots, n-1\rbrace)\to \mathrm{Top}_\ast$, which is strongly cocartesian (all faces are homotopy pushouts), but not cartesian (the initial space is the homotopy limit of the remaining diagram) for any $n$.
My question is, does anybody have a nice example or nice recipe about how to construct an example? (heavy machinery is welcome)
Here is what I tried, but was not able to fully work it out. My idea was to use that being cartesian is equivalent to the total fibre being contractible. Hence it would suffice to write down a cube, which is strongly cocartesian and has a total fibre which is not contractible. For this I wanted to use the standard example of a cofibre sequence, which is not a fibre sequence, namely $S^0\to \ast\to S^1$, which is described as a homotopy pushout square of $\ast\sqcup_{S^0}\ast$, which is not a cartesian square. I wanted to extend this as follows: let $\chi(\emptyset)=S^0$ and $\chi(\lbrace i\rbrace)=\ast$ and complete it by consecutevely taking pushouts, such that the cube is strongly cocartesian. I'd be happy, if somebody has an straight forward argument, as to why this should be. To me, already for $n=3$ it seems quite difficult to show that the resulting total fibre is not contractible (I know that total fibre can be computed "level-wise", but still my computation involves taking fibrant replacements and gets quite messy quite quickly). After that I would like to use an inductive argument, but was not able to see how that should go. Thanks for the help!
PS: This is claimed to be true in Arone and Ching's paper, Remark 1.5 and the beginning of section 3, but no example is given.

Just to satisfy my curiosity: when you say that a cube is cartesian iff its total fiber is contractible, do you define this total fiber as the homotopy fiber of the induced map from the initial vertex to the homotopy limit of the cube minus its initial vertex? Or is it a different condition that I am not aware of?

Hey, yes that is precisely how I define it.

It is a bit late here, so I may be missing something, but I don't see why taking $\chi(\varnothing)= S^0$ and $\chi(\{i\})=*$ and then iteratively taking pushouts yields a cube in which every face is a pushout. For example, if $n=3$, we have a cube

in which the front, top and left square are pushouts, and we decide that the right square is also a pushout, where $i_1$ and $i_2$ are the inclusions into the first and second component. What, then, should the morphism with a question mark be? In order for the bottom square to be a pushout, it seems it must be $i_2$, but in order for the back square to be a pushout, it seems it must be $i_1$. These two options are not homotopic, so I don't see how to build a strongly cocartesian square in this case. Again, I may be missing something, so I am happy to be corrected.
I propose to use a different square. For simplicity, I work in the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Spc}_*$ of pointed spaces, but you could turn this into an answer that works in the $1$-category $\mathrm{Top}_*$. Suppose given $n\geq 0$ and a collection $\{A_i\mid 1\leq i\leq n\}$ of pointed spaces. We build a cube $K\colon P(\{1,\ldots,n\})\to\mathrm{Spc}_*$ by putting $K(J)=\bigvee_{j\in J}A_j$, so that in particular $K(\varnothing)=*$, with the evident inclusion maps between these objects. (You can construct this purely $\infty$-categorically, but you can also just do it with $1$-categorical CW-complexes and then pass to the underlying $\infty$-category.) It is clear that this is a strongly cocartesian diagram when $n\geq 2$.
We now take the case where $n\geq 2$ and $A_j=S^1$ for all $j$. We will keep calling these spaces $A_j$ for some index $j$, because we want to keep track of the indices. To show $K$ is not cartesian in this case, we write $Q$ for the limit of $K$ minus its initial vertex, and must prove that $Q$ is not contractible. We do this by producing two points of $Q$ that are not connected via a path. The first one is the basepoint of $Q$. This map $\mathrm{bp}\colon *\to Q$ is classified (via the universal property of the limit) by the diagram $K$ itself. We let $K'\colon P(\{1,\ldots,n\})\to\mathrm{Spc}_*$ denote the diagram with the same objects and $1$-morphisms as $K$, but we ask for $j=2,3,\ldots,n$ that the homotopy filling the square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
* @>>> A_1\\
@VVV @V{i_1}VV\\
A_j @>{i_j}>> A_1\vee A_j
\end{CD}
$$
is not the constant path at the basepoint of $A_1\vee A_j$, but rather the path $[0,1]\to S^1=A_1\xrightarrow{i_1} A_1\vee A_j$, where the first map collapses $0$ and $1$ onto the basepoint of $S^1$. The homotopies in the other squares
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
* @>>> A_k\\
@VVV @V{i_k}VV\\
A_j @>{i_j}>> A_k\vee A_j
\end{CD}
$$
for $2\leq k,j\leq n$ are still the original ones from $K$, i.e. constant homotopies on the basepoint of $A_k\vee A_j$. You can extend these current $2$-homotopies to a whole $n$-cube $K'$ (if you want, I can write out details, which I am not doing right now because it is late and the remaining homotopies are sort of the "expected" ones.) If we remove the intial vertex of $K'$, we get the same diagram as when we do the same with $K$ (by constructing the higher homotopies of $K'$ in the "correct" way), so $K'$ also classifies a morphism $\neg\mathrm{bp}\colon*\to Q$. A homotopy $[0,1]\to Q$ from $\mathrm{bp}$ to $\neg\mathrm{bp}$ would be the same data as a homotopy from $K$ to $K'$, relative to the subdiagrams in which the initial vertex is removed. We hence get a homotopy, in the category $\mathrm{Spc}_*$, from the square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
* @>>> A_1\\
@VVV @V{i_1}VV\\
A_2 @>{i_2}>> A_1\vee A_2
\end{CD}
$$
with constant homotopy, to the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
* @>>> A_1\\
@VVV @V{i_1}VV\\
A_2 @>{i_2}>> A_1\vee A_2
\end{CD}
$$
with the "one-loop-in-$A_1$"-homotopy. That this homotopy takes place in $\mathrm{Spc}_*$ forces it to be a homotopy between squares, relative to the entire boundary of both squares. The existence of such a homotopy would hence imply that, in $A_1\vee A_2\simeq S^1\vee S^1$, the loop $i_1\colon S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$ around the left copy of $S^1$ is homotopic relative to the basepoint to the constant map $S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$ at the basepoint. This is a contradiction, so we find that $\mathrm{bp}\colon *\to Q$ and $\neg\mathrm{bp}\colon *\to Q$ are homotopically distinct points of $Q$. We have shown that $Q$ is not contractible, so the identity functor on $\mathrm{Spc}_*$ is not $n$-excisive for $n\geq 1$.
To finish the argument, note that the identity functor on $\mathrm{Spc}_*$ is not $0$-excisive because it does not invert the morphism $*\to S^1$.
